# While loop Java

Tags: java, while-loop

I need to calculate the number of times the while loop ran and how much total interest was paid after said amount of while loops.

Question is of interest rate and payments towards the debt. Prof is letting us write all code in main. 
"You have just purchased a stereo system that cost $1,000 on the following credit
plan: no down payment, an interest rate of 18% per year (and hence 1.5% per
month), and monthly payments of $50. The monthly payment of $50 is used to
pay the interest, and whatever is left is used to pay part of the remaining debt.
Hence, the first month you pay 1.5% of $1,000 in interest. That is $15 in interest.
So, the remaining $35 is deducted from your debt, which leaves you with a debt of
$965.00. The next month, you pay interest of 1.5% of $965.00, which is $14.48.
Hence, you can deduct $35.52 (which is $50 – $14.48) from the amount you owe.
Write a program that tells you how many months it will take you to pay off the
loan, as well as the total amount of interest paid over the life of the loan. Use a loop
to calculate the amount of interest and the size of the debt after each month. (Your
final program need not output the monthly amount of interest paid and remaining
debt, but you may want to write a preliminary version of the program that does output
these values.) Use a variable to count the number of loop iterations and hence,
the number of months until the debt is zero. You may want to use other variables as
well. The last payment may be less than $50 if the debt is small, but do not forget
the interest. If you owe $50, your monthly payment of $50 will not pay off your
debt, although it will come close. One month’s interest on $50 is only 75 cents."

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    double startCredit = 1000;
    double interestRate = .015;

    double payInterest = startCredit * interestRate;
    double payDebt = startCredit - payInterest;
    double paid = payInterest + payDebt;
    double newCredit = 965.0;

    while (newCredit > 0){
        double totalPaidInterest = 0;
        payInterest = newCredit * interestRate;
        payDebt = newCredit - payInterest;
        paid = payInterest + payDebt;
        newCredit = newCredit - paid;
        totalPaidInterest += payInterest;
        System.out.println("Total paid interest: " + totalPaidInterest);

    }
```

Comment: what is tje issue ????

Comment: You forgot to ask the question. :D

Comment: Please, try to formulate a question.

Comment: for number of times the loop runs, Have a counter and increment it each time the loop runs !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count while loops has been ran, just *count* them:

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    double startCredit = 1000;
    double interestRate = 0.015;

    double payInterest = startCredit * interestRate;
    double payDebt = startCredit - payInterest;
    double paid = payInterest + payDebt;
    double newCredit = 965.0;

    int count = 0; // <- While loop counter
    double totalPaidInterest = 0.0; // <- Total should be outside the loop

    while (newCredit > 0) {
      payInterest = newCredit * interestRate;
      payDebt = newCredit - payInterest;
      paid = payInterest + payDebt;
      newCredit = newCredit - paid;
      totalPaidInterest += payInterest;

      // You'd probably don't want to print out TOTAL values at each itteration
      //System.out.println("Total paid interest: " + totalPaidInterest);

      count += 1;
    }

    System.out.print("Total paid interest: ");
    System.out.println(totalPaidInterest);

    System.out.print("Loops: ");
    System.out.println(count);
  }
```

Comment: comes up as a compile error for the "count += 1;" part

Comment: @user3354429: the "count += 1;" is correct, so check your code; see my edit: I've put main function as it should be without any omissions.

Comment: it works, but it does the math wrong. it only outputs to "1" run of the while loop

Comment: @user3354429: Well, check your math then; it counts loops right: after the 1st loop the local variables' values are "payInterest = 14.475; payDebt = 950.525; paid = 965.0; newCredit = 0;"; so since newCredit == 0 while loop breaks and you have 1 run of the while loop.